# Create a new String with Duplicate Letters

Tags: c#, arrays, string, tostring, to-char

I am trying to create a string that inserts a duplicate letter from the original into the modified.  For example, the output of one run would be:

Original word:

> stack

Output:

> sstack, sttack, staack, stacck, stackk

Does that make sense?  I have this so far, and I feel i am close, but I am suing the wrong method to reassemble the string.  Any help would be appreciated:

```
 // Use ToCharArray to convert string to array.                
 char[] array = originalWord.ToCharArray();

 // Loop through array.
 for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
 {
    // Get character from array.
    char letter = array[i];
    string result = array.ToString();
    string result2 = string.Join("", result.Select(x => x + letter));
    Console.Write(result2);
 }
```

Comment: There's really no need to convert a string to a char array. You can index a string just like an array anyway. So instead of `char letter = array[i]` you can just do `char letter = originalWord[i]`

Comment: @AppDeveloper Permalinking to your answer in a comment on the question seems dangerously close to spamming...

Comment: @LeonNewswanger - sorry if that is so!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
var original = "stack";
for (int i = 0; i < original.Length; i++)
    Console.WriteLine(original.Insert(i, original[i].ToString()));
```

Comment: Thanks Thomas.  Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [String.Insert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.string.insert.aspx) to insert a string at a given index into another string.

```
IEnumerable<string> strings = originalWord
    .Select((c, idx) => originalWord.Insert(idx, c.ToString()));
```

Answer (score 1):

Fixed :

```
        string originalWord = "stack";
        // Use ToCharArray to convert string to array.                
        char[] array = originalWord.ToCharArray();

        // Loop through array.
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            // Get character from array.
            char letter = array[i];
            string result = originalWord.Insert(i, letter.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }
```

The Linq way :

```
IEnumerable<string> words = originalWord.Select((letter, i) => originalWord.Insert(i, letter.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`String.Insert()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.string.insert.aspx) method like;

```
string s = "stack";

for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
{
   Console.WriteLine (s.Insert(i, s[i].ToString()));
}
```

Here is a [`DEMO`](http://ideone.com/wZLMQr).

Oh god, already aded 3 answers when I writing it. Damn..

Comment: exact duplicate of Thomas' answer

Comment: @Forty-Two unfortunately yes. When I writing it, people added their answers and my browser doesn't update them. I will delete it.